# How to block a connection to a specific FTP server

Tags: ftp, connection, keylogger

I'm thinking about writing an anti-keylogger/anti RAT application. Basically, what I want it to do is this:

1. Monitor outgoing ftp traffic (maybe monitor all outgoing traffic and have an option to filter by ftp)
2. Analyze headers to find potential keyloggers/RATs
3. Sniff out the FTP address for any such connections
4. Block (or give user the option to block) connections to these addresses

I think I can handle steps 1-3, and I know I could block *all* FTP traffic, but how could I go about blocking specific addresses?

On a side note, can anyone suggest some libraries that might make steps 1-3 easier? Or libaries that'll do step 4, if they exist. I don't mind writing code to target multiple OS.

Comment: @Jonatan I'd like it to be OS-insensitive. But I guess I could just detect the OS and then use either iptables/netsh/ipfw accordingly

Answer (score 0):

[Snort](http://www.snort.org/) allows you to monitor incoming/outgoing traffic and works based on a set of rules specified in a file. Once you've detected traffic going out that has a certain IP/port/body using snort, use [SnortSAM](http://www.snortsam.net/) in conjunction with a firewall to block traffic to that IP/port.

Comment: That's nice and all, but I'm writing software that I want to be able to deploy to other machines, so I can't rely on other applications.

Comment: Even though there are libraries for C++ (libpcap) that allow you to capture traffic from an interface, these libraries work atop the OS and by the time you've seen the packet it's already been sent/received. You'll end up having manipulating the OS's routing table/firewall in any case, and you'd have to write OS specific routines for modifying these resources if you'd like to run on multiple platforms, which is very similar to what SnortSAM already does.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much exactly what I want to do. Capture ftp traffic, find a keylogger, get its address, and block that address for later, so that further packets won't be sent. Basically if you combined snort and snortSAM. Well, a small subset of what the two combined could do. I guess the question might have been better phrased as "How to/What libraries will help to access/change firewall rules programmatically for multiple platforms"

Comment: Not sure if there are any libraries specifically designed for this - what language are you working in? I'd venture to say that your best bet will be writing platform specific bash/ksh scripts that add an IP to the platform's firewall, then calling these from your application

Comment: Meh, I dunno. I kinda figured I'd write it in C++, but I don't really care. Maybe I'll write the bulk of it in C# or even python and then just write the tricky stuff in C++ and wrap it up. The bash thing actually sounds like a pretty good idea, though. Of course then I'd have to touch up my bash skillz..